# Transform one object to another with animation

Tags: objects, transforms

basicly I have one object its curved text and I would like to transform it to not to be curved text in animation, they are two separated objects I cant you shape keys, How I can easy do this

[image]

Edit: They have same amount of verts. they can share same obj. data

Comment: imho you can either deform the whole object, or use shape keys, or transform every single letter separately. The two last methods could be helped by snapping to get straight alignment, so to result in the end "not curved". For the first one, I would try a lattice deform, or a curve deform...

Comment: I correct myself: looking better, in the curved version each letter seems not deformed, just rotated. So, I would use shape keys or separate object for each letter, then animate each.

Comment: But, if you can use "text" objects (not letters meshes), you could also start from the "straight" text and use the "text on curve" setting, using a curve to achieve the same effect, then you could animate the curve from arc to linear to get the desired effect... basically it's always easier to produce the curve and then reverse the effect in animation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I mean in my third comment, ie: if you can use "text" objects (not letters meshes), you could also start from the "straight" text and use the "text on curve" setting, using a curve to achieve the same effect, then you could animate the curve from arc to linear to get the desired effect... basically it's always easier to produce the curve and then reverse the effect in animation...

here the text object is "deformed" by a "flattened" curve.

[image]

You can simply animate the curve deformation in reverse...

If you have text meshes instead, you could use shape keys like this:

[image]

And even here you could just animate the shape key values in reverse...

In the end, about other solution I suggested in comments above:

- deforming the whole object is not feasible: letters will be distorted
- separate single letters and try to animate each from rotated to straight is feasible but extremely difficult, complicated and, imho, not worth.

I would use one of the methods described above, instead.